# Content type 'null' not supported returned by Spring RESTTemplate getForObject method

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-mvc

I have a simple REST method in a Spring MVC controller as follows which has a signature of:

> @RequestMapping(value="/person/{personId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
>       public @ResponseBody Object getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") String personId) {
>       ...
>      }

The output is type `Object` because several different data types are returned from this method.

When called from a test program within the Spring MVC application, as follows:

```
private static void getPerson() {
    logger.info(Rest.class.getName() + ".getPerson() method called."); 

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Person person = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/Library/rest/person/1", Person.class);   

    ObjectMapper responseMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    ...
    }
```

The response is `Content type 'null' not supported` and the call fails.

Can anyone advise why?

When called from a test program in another application which doesn't use Spring but which makes HTTP GET requests, the controller method is called properly and works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(VERSION_CHECK_READ_TIMEOUT);
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
Person person = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/Library/rest/person/1", Person.class);
```

If above doesn't work you can try using a `Entity` approach like:

```
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  // Prepare acceptable media type
  List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
  acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML); // Set what you need

  // Prepare header
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
  HttpEntity<Person> entity = new HttpEntity<Person>(headers);

  // Send the request as GET
  try {
      ResponseEntity<PersonList> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/Library/rest/person/1", HttpMethod.GET, entity, PersonList.class);
      // Add to model
      model.addAttribute("persons", result.getBody().getData());

  } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e);
  }
```

There are many [useful examples here](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-3-rest-web-service-provider-and_28.html).

Hope to help

Comment: Thanks but concerning the first, where does VERSION_CHECK_READ_TIMEOUT live? And for the second, the parameter ("") causes bother.

Comment: @MrMorgan sorry, check again.

Comment: I have no such `getData()` method in the `Person` class. However, despite everything the code still returns Content type 'null' not supported which is odd given that I've set the media type to JSON. –